# Обновление списка внутри словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Программа получает на ввод первой строкой кол-во команд, далее **имитирует** работу пространства имён.

```
n = int(input())
dic = {}
cmd, namesp, arg = '', '', ''
while n:
    n -= 1
    cmd, namesp, arg = input().split()
    if cmd == 'create':  # if create new namespace
        if not dic:
            dic[arg] = [namesp]
        else:
            dic[arg] = [namesp]+[dic[arg]]
    if cmd == 'add':
        if not dic:  # add to namespace new value
             dic[namesp] = [arg]
        else:
            dic[namesp] = [arg]+[dic[namesp]] #ВОТ ТУТ ОШИБКА
    if cmd == 'get':
        if arg in dic[namesp]:  # get from namespace value
            print(arg)
```

В строках, где должны обновляться данные словаря по ключу ( он хранит пару ключ - список), происходит ошибка. Вот прмер такой ошибки:
Ввод:

```
9
add global a
create foo global
add foo b
```

Когда мы достигаем добавления `b` в `foo` происходит ошибка:

```
line 16, in <module>
    dic[namesp] = [arg]+[dic[namesp]]
KeyError: 'foo'
```

**Что идёт не так?** Как в моём случае обновлять значения по уже существующему ключу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка здесь:

Вместо

```
if not dic:
```

нужно использовать

```
if namesp not in dic:
```

(и тоже высшее - `if arg not in dic:`)